# Error running test in AngularJS tutorial, step-3

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I get the following when trying to run the end-to-end test in the angular tutorial (http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03)...

I did "git checkout -f step-3" so it's straight from the repo...

```
[2013-04-05 07:17:07.774] [WARN] config - "/" is proxied, you should probably change urlRoot to avoid conflicts
INFO [testacular]: Testacular server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 26.0 (Mac)]: Connected on socket id CamYxe8MuPk52Agq6g5L
WARN [proxy]: failed to proxy /app/index.html (Error: connect ECONNREFUSED)
WARN [proxy]: failed to proxy /app/index.html (Error: connect ECONNREFUSED)
```

I'm running the app inside a Rails app, which is being served by WEBrick on port 3000.
So I change the testacula config to...

```
proxies = {
'/': 'http://localhost:3000/'
};
```

...then the test runs but fails with

```
Chrome 26.0 (Mac) PhoneCat App Phone list view should filter the phone list as user types into the search box FAILED
expect repeater '.phones li' count toBe 3
/Users/paul/rails_projects/angularjs/public/angular-phonecat/test/e2e/scenarios.js:15:7: expected 3 but was 0
```

So it seems it's not navigating to the page correctly.
Anyone have any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Update your angular-phonecat/config/testacular-e2e.conf.js proxy to this:

```
proxies = {
  '/': 'http://localhost:3000/angular-phonecat/'
};
```

The tests in angular-phonecat/test/e2e/scenarios.js are expecting to be able to reach:

```
http://localhost:3000/app/index.html
```

Updating the proxy to the above configuration will fix this (or you could move all the files from /Users/paul/rails_projects/angularjs/public/angular-phonecat/* directly into your public folder)

Answer (score 1):

As Chris has said, (I upped his comment)

I am running MAMP so I had to change it to use port :80/angular-phonecat

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply running scripts/web-server.js then just run the server:

```
→ ./scripts/web-server.js 
Http Server running at http://localhost:8000/
```

Notice that **8000** is the correct port and update the e2e config file:

```
// config/karma-e2e.conf.js

proxies: {
  '/': 'http://localhost:8000/' //was :3000
}
```

Now run e2e tests and it should be fine:

```
→ karma start config/karma-e2e.conf.js
```